# path for echo binary location

Tags: adb

I am unable to find the "echo" binary in the /bin path (supposedly the path for storage of essential binaries) on Galaxy S2 on which I am working on. And yes, the "echo" command is perfectly working when I tried it on adb shell. I have also tried looking into sbin, xbin and other such directories. 
Does somebody know where else I can find it?

Answer (score 2):

Yepp, in the shell. `echo` is a built-in command, see [Why is echo a shell built in command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/why-is-echo-a-shell-built-in-command), [Wikipedia: Shell built-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin), and [The echo command](http://www.linfo.org/echo.html). So you won't find any "`echo` binary", as it is contained in the `sh` command.

Comment: Sorry, actually what I meant was an executable, and not a binary. So, I can see "mv", "ls" and other such executables.. but not "echo" although echo command works.                  I require to use the path for this executable in another system call.

Comment: All the same. The `echo` command is, as I wrote, built into the shell. The shell is executed when you log in (e.g. via `adb shell`), so there's no need for any separate executable or symlink (as it is done with `busybox`, for example).

Answer (score 1):

If the system shell on your Android device is an `mksh` (i.e. `/system/bin/mksh`, normally), and the `mksh` version is recent enough that it supports direct builtin calls already, *then* you can create a link or symlink from `echo` to `mksh` (anywhere not mounted `noexec`). This will then expose the shell’s `echo` builtin as externally callable utility.

Note that you should normally be using the builtin, not an external utility, for speed, if possible.

Disclaimer: I’m the [`mksh`](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) maintainer.